# NASM and a question about ADC - ASM 8086

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

I study assembly on High-school and I would like to try to make assembly programs at home.
I downloaded NASM but I don't understand how to run the .s files with it - if you can write a simple way here to run it I'd glad :-)

and in addition I have a question: when I use ADC for exmaple: AL = 01 and BL = 02, and CF = 1, when I make this:
ADC AL,BL
Will AL be 3 or 4? (with the CF addition or without?)

Thank you!!

Comment: Dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688248/adc-instruction-in-asm-8086

Answer (score 2):

From your command prompt (bash for Linux):

```
nasm myasm.s -o myasm.bin -f bin
```

This is the basic command line structure. I don't know which OS you are writing on, but for Linux use:

```
nasm -h  // (I believe, or --help)
```

for a list of command parameters.

Anyway, the `-o` tells nasm what the output file is, and the `-f` tells nasm what the format is. In this example, we are simply writing a flat binary.

For a lot more information see [Compiling an assembly program...](http://en.kioskea.net/faq/1559-compiling-an-assembly-program-with-nasm)

For more information on using ADC, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2688248/adc-instruction-in-asm-8086).

Comment: nasm -hf to see the list of the available output formats.
Mainly, nasm -f win32 for Windows, nasm -f elf for Linux, and nasm -f macho for OSX.