# ADC instruction in ASM 8086

Tags: assembly, x86-16, machine-instruction

When I use `ADC` for exmaple:

```
AL = 01 and BL = 02, and CF = 1
```

when I make this:

```
ADC AL,BL
```

Will `AL` be `3` or `4`? (with the `CF` addition or without?)

Comment: Try and get into the habit of testing these things out for yourself - it's a great way to learn.

Comment: +1 Paul R.  Tal, you will learn much faster and get much more accurate results if you test such things on your own.  In the time that it took you to enter this question and to clarify things in the various responses below you could have tested each and every scenario and had a definitive answer, all while learning some fundamental things about CPUs, registers and flags.

Answer (score 12):

Few things about the `8086` `ADC` instruction:

```
Syntax: adc dest, src
dest: memory or register
src:  memory, register, or immediate
Action: dest = dest + src + CF
```

Clearly the action says the Carry Flag (`CF`) will be included in the addition so the result will be `4` not `3`.

Comment: and what if I do this: AX = FF, BX = FF, CF = 1
and ADC AX,BX
What will happen? I mean, where will the computer store the extra byte?

Thank you!!

Comment: @Tal: If you do that, AX will be 0x01FF and CF will be 0.  There is no extra byte.

Answer (score 6):

It is no different than adding in base 10.

```
 99
+11

9+1 is zero carry the 1
9+1+carry is 1 carry the 1
```

The result of the above decimal math is 10 with a carry of 1, or 110 if you want to think of it that way.

For binary start with a one bit adder, here is a truth table:

```
000 0 0
001 0 1
010 0 1
011 1 0
100 0 1
101 1 0
110 1 0
111 1 1
```

the left column of three bits are the input combinations, two operands and carry in,
the second column is carry out and the third column is the result

so 1+1 with no carry is 110 in the left column and the result is 0 carry the 1.

Not any different than the decimal math above just much simpler, when you add up a column in decimal, operand a, operand b, carry.  The result is the answer modulo 10 and the carry is the result/10.  copy the carry to the top of the next column and repeat for ever.  as demonstrated with 99+11 or 999+111, etc.

For the simpler two bit add with no carry the result is the xor of the inputs and the carry out is the and of the two inputs.  You could implement add with carry using two add without carry adders chained or do it directly.  The result is set when there are an odd number of onces or odd parity, which is two xors  r = a xor b xor carry in.  The carry out I am struggling with at the moment perhaps someone can help.

so an 8 bit 0xFF + 0xFF with carry set will give

```
        1
 11111111
+11111111
```

This shows 0xff + 0xff with a "carry the one" coming in before you start.

look at it one column at a time from the right just like decimal math

```
1+1+1 = 1 carry the 1
next column
1+1+1 = 1 carry the 1
...
```

this continues and you end up with 
0xFF with the carry bit set

So if you had only an 8 bit add with carry you could add up two numbers as wide as you have memory.

Lets look at a 16 bit add:

```
 0x1234
+0xABCD
```

You could just do the math with a 16 bit add, 0xBE01.

or with an 8 bit adder:

```
clear the carry bit
add with carry 0x34+0xCD result 0x01 carry set
add with carry 0x12+0xAB result 0xBE carry clear
```

so the answer is 0xBE01

Or using a 4 bit adder if all you have is a 4 bit alu

```
clear the carry bit
add with carry 0x4+0xD = 0x1 carry bit set
add with carry 0x3+0xC = 0x0 carry bit set
add with carry 0x2+0xB = 0xE carry bit clear
add with carry 0x1+0xA = 0xB carry bit clear
```

again the result 0xBE01 carry bit clear

we could do this with single bits as well or a 3 bit adder, so long as it is binary it is trivial.

All useful processors must have some way to add the carry bit so that you can widen the alu.  Sometimes there are separate add and adc, some the adc is an extra step or the most painful would be an add without carry and use a branch if carry clear with an add immediate under it.

This is also why shifts or rotates rotate through the carry bit, so you can do a bit shift wider than the width of a register/memory location.

binary multiplication is painfully simple compared to decimal, but I will spare you that one and let you think about it.

Yes, you could have and should have written a program to try this out.  And still can, I could be intentionally leading you down a path of misinformation.

Answer (score 4):

`AL` will be 4.  `ADC` means `add with carry`, so of course the carry *is* summed in.  `CF` gets set back to 0, since there is no carry out of the addition in question.

Comment: and what if I do this: AX = FF, BX = FF, CF = 1 and ADC AX,BX What will happen? I mean, where will the computer store the extra byte? Thank you!!

Comment: @Tal, AX and BX are fully able to store more than one byte (since you're not using single-byte registers like AL and BL here!) so the result will be `1FF` in AX and, again, CF to 0.

Answer (score 4):

It will be 4.  ADC (add with carry) adds in an extra 1 if the carry flag (CF) is 1.  See the full description of the opcode [here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2008/readings/i386/ADC.htm).